# finding angle between one point and another point with ray

Tags: angle

I'm trying to figure out the angle between the direction to an objective point relative to a player looking a certain direction.

This will be used in making a direction indicator for a game.

Here's a diagram made in Geogebra that shows the scenario

[image]

Updated diagram to avoid confusion

I have X,Y coordinates of the player and objective and I have the rotation of the player to work with.

Comment: do you know about the dot/scalar product in basic vector mathematics?

Comment: I've heard of it but never learned much about it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In two dimensions, you can use the scalar or dot product of two vectors:

$$
\mathbf{a}\cdot \mathbf{b}=\left(\begin{matrix} a_x  \\ a_y  \end{matrix}\right)\cdot\left(\begin{matrix} b_x  \\ b_y  \end{matrix}\right) = a_xb_x + a_yb_y = |\mathbf{a}| |\mathbf{b}|\cos\theta
$$

where $\theta$ is the angle between the two vectors (and which could be either the acute or obtuse angle, depending on the directions of the vectors).

So, you'll need to find the vectors from

a) the player to the objective and

b) the player to the playerview

To get these vectors, imagine the player has coordinates $(p_x,p_y)$ and the objective has coordinates $(q_x,q_y)$. 
The vector from the player to the objective will then be:

$$\left(\begin{matrix} q_x - p_x  \\ q_y-p_y  \end{matrix}\right)$$
(You can do the same thing for the playerview if needed)

Then you need to calculate the magnitudes (lengths) of these vectors, and their scalar product via the middle relationship above.
The angle will then be the inverse cosine of the dot product divided by the product of their magnitudes.

Edit:

Instead, if you know the angle for the playerview relative to north, you can use the dot product of the northwards (unit) vector (which is $\left(\begin{matrix} 0  \\ 1  \end{matrix}\right)$) and the vector above to find the angle from north to the objective, and then add (or subtract as necessary) the two angles to find the overall angle.

Comment: ok so I would need to get the vectors from the player to objective and player to playerview and from that I can find the angle between the direction of the objective and the way the player is looking

Comment: exactly! :) can you do that?

Comment: I might be making another question >.< I've got the "I know I learned that sometime before but have now forgotten it" problem :P

Comment: I mean I know I have what I need ( objective location , player location and player rotation.)

Comment: ok so what information is exactly needed for "a" and "b"

Comment: the coordinates of each thing, see edit :)

Comment: ok so I was somewhat confused for a second >.< the diagram is somewhat misleading. The playerview isn't actually a point but a rotational value

Comment: ok well that changes things a bit... how are you getting/measuring the "rotational value"?

Comment: I will gather more data...

Comment: ok so this diagram might be more explanatory http://image.prntscr.com/image/b94a276121bb4fada081b6d7dfd4977e.png